# How to split a list to multiple lists avoiding an imperative approach in scala

Tags: scala

Given a scenario where I have to iterate a list and from it produce multiple lists based on the objects in the list I cannot figure out how to do this without avoiding using an imperative approach. To be more specific say I have a list of items [a, b, c, d] and would like to produce say three new lists based on different attributes of the items:
[a1, b1, c1, d1], [a2, b2, c2, d2], [a3, b3, c3, d3].

I have produced a trivial example below which is probably how I would have done it in java but I am wondering if someone can recommend a way to do this while avoiding the imperative style?

```
case class Atom(nuc: Int, prot: Int, neut: Int)

class Splitter(list: Array[Atom]) {

    val nucs: ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer()
    val prots: ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer()
    val neuts: ArrayBuffer[(Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer()

    list foreach { atom =>
        nucs += (atom.nuc -> atom.nuc * 3)
        prots += (atom.prot -> atom.prot * 4)
        neuts += (atom.neut -> atom.neut * 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that splitting is a dividing collection into smaller collections using some criteria. You want to transform your collection into three other collections and it is not splitting :)

If you in a feature want to split collection, consider using `groupBy` function, see example below:


```List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).groupBy{
        case item if (item % 2 == 0) => "Even"
        case item if (item % 2 == 1) => "Odd"
}```


```res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(Odd -> List(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), Even -> List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
val (nucs, prots, neuts) =
  list.map(atom => (atom.nuc*3, atom.prot*4, atom.neut*5)).unzip3
```